# Swift NavigationLink to Sheet

Tags: swift, swiftui

i have a problem with my NavigationLink.
Soo, I want my NavigationLink point to an sheet.
That works, when i click on the area with the text. When i click on the area with no text, it opens the destination of the NavigationLink.

So i made the sheet toggle boolean, that I have, as the "isActive" from the Navigation link.
Now i can click on the whole Navigation Link and I get the sheet.
But, when I close the Sheet, it shows me the original Navigation Link Destination for a second and close itself after.

I hope someone know my problem and can understand me.

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text(""), isActive: $showJobCreator){
    newJobPlaceholder()
    Spacer()                  
}.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{
    showJobCreator.toggle()
}).sheet(isPresented: $showJobCreator, content: {
    newJobCreator(state: showJobCreator)
})
```

This is the part of the code.
Thank you!

Comment: Use a Button vs. NavigationLink

Comment: The  boolean that you use as the isActive parameter can't be manipulated after you set it to true. It's automatically reset to false when you navigate back. If you programmatically change it to false, it will cause unpredictable behavior at runtime. Set it to true when the user taps and don't change it to false anywhere else in your code. It should be marked with the @State property wrapper and declared as private. Use a different bool to control presentation of your sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you put an overlay on the Rectangle and use it, the onTapGesture will be executed even if you click on the background without text.

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text("")) {
    Rectangle()
        .frame(width: 330, height: 60, alignment: .center)
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .cornerRadius(7)
        .overlay(
            Text("Test")
                .font(.system(size: 23, weight: .semibold))
        )
        .onTapGesture {
           
        }
}
```

Hope this answer answered your question!